# group libvirt missing from /etc/group

Tags: 18.04, permissions, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have installed qemu-kvm and virt-manager to Ubuntu 18.04 machine. While trying to add my user to libvirt group I got following error:

```
sudo groupadd libvirt
groupadd: group 'libvirt' already exists

sudo adduser $USER libvirt
Adding user `xxxxxx' to group `libvirt' ...
gpasswd: group 'libvirt' does not exist in /etc/group
adduser: `/usr/bin/gpasswd -a xxxxxx libvirt' returned error code 3. Exiting.

cat /etc/group | grep libvirt    
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:134:

sudo cat /etc/gshadow | grep libvirt
kvm:!::libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:!::
libvirt-qemu:!::libvirt-qemu
```

Comment: Does `sudo grpck -r` report anything?

Comment: @steeldriver "sudo grpck -r" did not report any thing

Comment: Note: The install of libvirt-daemon-system package goes through almost the same [commands that you tried](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/tree/debian/libvirt-daemon-system.postinst?h=ubuntu/bionic-devel#n29) with some extras for when the group was renamed from libvirtd->libvirt. It would stumble over the same. Does in your case it maybe exist in /etc/gshadow but not in /etc/group confusing the tools?

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt I have added output of /etc/gshadow in the question

Comment: Did you get any errors when you attempted to install qemu-kvm and virt-manager? Please [edit] the output of `sudo dpkg-query -l qemu-kvm virt-manager` into your question. thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. The error was related to my system, nothing wrong with the libvirt installation. There was a group with name ***libvirt*** in AD my system is authenticating. That was causing a conflict in creating a local group and add user to that.

The solution was to filter it in /etc/sssd/conf.d/10-libvirt.conf

```
  [nss]
  filter_groups = libvirt
```

and restart sssd service

```
systemctl restart sssd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was some more commands that deleted the group... I installed qemu-kvm and virt-manager on 18.04.3. I deleted from group and gshadow. Then did a reinstall of libvirt-daemon-system based on @ChristianEhrhardt comment. After reinstall the group is added back and user that did the install is added to the group. Helps?

```
user$ grep libvirt /etc/group
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:130:
user$ sudo grep libvirt /etc/gshadow
libvirt-qemu:!::libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:!::

user$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libvirt-daemon-system

user$ grep libvirt /etc/group
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:130:
libvirt:x:129:user
user$ sudo grep libvirt /etc/gshadow
libvirt-qemu:!::libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:!::
libvirt:!::user
```